# How do I upgrade Management Engine/AMT firmware for Lenovo T440s given a Linux installation?

Tags: linux, lenovo-laptop, firmware, intel-amt

I have a T440s. CVE-2017-5689 / INTEL-SA-00075 is looming. Lenovo released updates:

https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/product_security/LEN-14963

Their motherboard BIOS updates usually have both a Windows-required option, and a live USB update option. However this one only has the Windows-required option, as I'm checking now. They haven't even released updates for all hardware models so maybe things are just in the works, but they haven't indicated so in anything I've seen.

In the mean time, I found these instructions on some wiki:

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Intel_Active_Management_Technology_(AMT)#Firmware_update

But they seem involved and somewhat confusing, and I'm wondering if it's outdated besides. Being a wiki it could change, but it currently seems to say I need to:

- Install Windows PE on a USB stick
- Extract 2 files from *some other firmware file* from IBM's website using Wine:

  - A CMD I'll run to do the update
  - A driver I need to figure out how to load.

This seems sketchy to me. Can anybody corroborate this? Is there another way to go about it?

On a side note, isn't Lenovo a little more responsible than this to take care of flaws in its product? Or did I agree somewhere in a contract that I only run Windows? The lack of support, transparency, and preparedness seems completely unacceptable to me for such a serious defect in their product.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a way using native Linux (or even DOS/EFI: just use the respective tools in the System Tools download, instead of the Linux ones).

Lenovo provides us with two things: **Management Engine Interface** (MEI) or Management Engine Software and the **Management Engine Firmware** (ME).
The former is needed to provide a driver (HECI) to access and flash the ME, the latter is the flash utility plus the flash image.
As we use Linux, *we only need the flash tools and firmware*.
In my case it was called "`r0dmu01w.exe`", I will use "`FWPkg.exe`" from now on.

1. Extract the firmware using innoextract `$ innoextract FWPkg.exe` or wine `$ wine FWPkg.exe`
2. This will create some a folder "`app`" in your current directory (innoextract) or the folder "`ME`" in wine root's "`C:\DRIVERS\`" directory that will be created if needed (wine). We will only be interested in the "`ME_<version>_[Consumer/Corporate]_*_Production.bin`" file(s) (the firmware image) and the "`MEUpdate.CMD`" flash script which calls a "`FWUpdLcl(64).exe`".

Intel does provide a Linux version of this tool to distributors however, we can download it [here](https://www.win-raid.com/t596f39-Intel-Management-Engine-Drivers-Firmware-amp-System-Tools.html) (inofficial!).
These are the intel ME System Tools, I'm having a ME v11, so I downloaded "Intel CSME System Tools v11", I'll call it "`METools.rar`" from now on.

1. Extract the files `$ unrar x METools.rar`
2. Inside the extracted directory, there will be a "`FWUpdate/LINUX(64)/Portable/FWUpdLcl`" file.
3. Go to the path of said file and add execute permissions: `$ chmod +x FWUpdLcl`
4. Have a look at the "`MEUpdate.CMD`" script with a line that should look a bit like that:

   ```
   %~dp0FWUpdLcl64.exe -F %~dp0ME_<version>_[Consumer/Corporate]_*_Production.BIN -OEMID XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX -generic -allowsv
   ```

   We are only interested in the OEMID-flag, I'll refer to it as `$OEMID`.
   Alternatively you can use the "`MEInfo`" utility, this however requires `iomem=relaxed` to be set in the kernel load command line.
5. Now use the Linux tool as admin and update your firmware, you use the consumer variant if your device does *not* support intel AMT (AMT-enabled CPUs have the "vPro" logo on them):

   ```
   # FWUpdLcl -F <path/to/binfile> -OEMID $OEMID -allowsv
   ```

   The generic flag isn't available on Linux, the only documentation I could find was "Perform the update through MEI without credentials" -- but we don't seem to need it.
   AllowSV allows Same-Version updates.

That's it, you should now have an updated ME firmware.

---

Edit:
I just found that [someone](https://www.glasen-hardt.de/2017/12/11/intel-management-engine-des-t460-unter-linux-aktualisieren/) has already found the same solution (in German), linked for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

The recipe (the exact revision at a time was [this one](http://www.thinkwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Intel_Active_Management_Technology_(AMT)&oldid=58188)) worked for my Thinkpad X2*x*0 (with original OS upgraded to GNU/Linux and OpenBSD) with minor changes.

Preparing the `winpe3_x86.iso` was relatively easy. I booted it, and the necessary mentioned firmware upgrade and driver "packages" I have had on USB flash drive in the form of two `.exe` files.

> - A CMD I'll run to do the update

You'll find the CMD file in each firmware upgrade "package", after extraction by launching the exe file when booted in WinPE environment. For T440, the desired one with the vulnerability fix is most likely https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/downloads/DS038194

> - A driver I need to figure out how to load.

The recipe mentions: *... you need to load HECI driver with "drvload HECI.inf"*, and links to *Intel AMT Management Engine Interface for Windows*. The link (redirect) was broken, however one should be able to locate it for his/her platform with the search field at https://support.lenovo.com.

The driver successfully loaded with `drvload` command (it has been extracted to `C:\DRIVERS\WIN\AMT\MEI\MEI\HECI.inf`; C: was my USB flash drive), however it somehow did not work for me, the `MEUpdate.CMD` failed.

I succeeded with a different "package": *Intel Management Engine Interface 7.1 and Serial Over LAN (SOL) driver*. After loading HECI.inf (that has been extracted to `c:\DRIVERS\WIN\AMT\ME_SW\Drivers\MEI\HECI.inf`), I did also load `C:\DRIVERS\WIN\AMT\ME_SW\Drivers\SOL\mesrle.inf`, but am not 100% sure it was necessary - I do not want to repeat the experiment.

By the way, don't forget to enable Intel AMT in the BIOS setup, before the firmware upgrade, and disable it afterwards ;)